# String variable inside OnClickListener returns null

Tags: java, android

I have a `String` variable `userBoat` that I'm trying to initialize inside an `onClick` if statement. Unfortunately when I try to call it from another activity the variable is returning `null`. I've tried initializing it as a global variable but then the other activity simply returns the value of the global variable - not the updated value from within the `onClick` if statement. Thanks in advance for the help.

Here's my code for the `MainActivity` where I am declaring the variable:

```java
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (mBarberi.isPressed()) {
        userBoat = "AJB";

        myRef3.push().setValue("Date: " + date() + " || Boat: AJB");
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Thanks.class));
    }
}
```

And here is my code for the activity where I'm trying to receive the variable and assign it to a calendar API

```java
public void onClick(View v) {
    MainActivity mainReference = new MainActivity();

    if (mNone.isPressed()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)
            .setData(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI)
            .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_ALL_DAY, true)
            .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, mainReference.userBoat + "  No O.T.");

        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Where `mainReference.userBoat` refers to the variable in question.

Comment: It's a very bad practice to create instances of Activity classes. Start by avoiding that

Comment: @Tuqay You can just send some links and points where he made a mistake (like you did with Activity).

Comment: Yea I'm new to OOP.  Got this whole app to work by some miracle with the exception of this last variable.  Really appreciate the help and tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just pass `userBoat` as extra for the `Intent` and then receive it in the `Thanks` class.

Here is an example of the code in the `MainActivity`:

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Thanks.class);
intent.putExtra(USER_BOAT_KEY, userBoat);

startActivity(intent);
```

`USER_BOAT_KEY` can be a static string somewhere in your code.
`public static final String USER_BOAT_KEY = "user-boat_key"`

And here is how to get it in the `Thanks.class`:

```java
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

if (extras.containsKey(USER_BOAT_KEY)) {
    String userBoat = extras.getString(USER_BOAT_KEY);
    
    // now you can use it here
}
```

Comment: Thanks Yaroslav.  Really appreciate the help brotha.